# Search for data.frame indices according to multiple column criteria - how to speed up for large data sets?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, search, data.table

I have a large data.frame (50M rows) and need to find indices which match a multiple column criteria.

I made a toy example to illustrate the problem.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101429/speeding-up-searching-for-indices-within-a-large-r-data-frame) that it's faster to search though data.tables than data.frames so I converted data.frame into a data.table object

```
cases<-c(1,3,5)
women<-c("Julia", "Judith", "Juno", "Jane", "Joanna")
data.df<-data.frame("id" = 1:5, "age" = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60), "name" = c("Joanna","Joe", "Julia", "Juno", "John"))

library(data.table)
data.dt<-as.data.table(data.df)
setkey(data.dt, "id")
```

I want the results vector to contain age values of records which pass the multiple column criteria, in this case 20, 40, NA. I search using the for loop (which is probably a silly approach, any tips would be greatly appreciated here)

```
results<-vector()
for (i in 1:length(cases)){
which_id<-cases[i]
ind<-data.dt[id==which_id & name %in% women, which=TRUE]
if(length(ind)==0){results[i]<-NA}
else{results[i]<-data.dt$age[ind]}
}
```

This would do on a smaller data set but with 500K records in cases and 50M in data.df it is going to take an excess of 12 hours to run. There must be a simpler way, can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Do you want ```data.dt[J(cases)][name %in% women]```

Comment: please see this vignette

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html

Comment: After reading the vignette I see that I was using data.tables same way as if I was using data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to filter his dataset by `id` first and then to return `age` if the `name` is found in `women` (and `NA` otherwise).

Below are different `data.table` approaches which return the expected result

```
20 40 NA
```

for the example case. However, performance may vary for the production dataset.

#### 1. Filtering by `id`, matching on `women`

```
setkey(data.dt, id)
data.dt[cases][name %in% women, Age := age][, Age]
```

Here, integer matching is used as `name` has been turned into factor by OP's call to `data.frame()`. (If `name` is of type character `%chin%` could have been used).

To make sure `NA` is returned in case of no matches, an *update in place* is used which puts `NA` by default.

Note that [Cole's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204609/search-for-data-frame-indices-according-to-multiple-column-criteria-how-to-spe#comment104628167_59204609) approach `data.dt[J(cases)][name %in% women]` would only return a  filtered dataset with 2 rows but not the expected result.

#### 2. Filtering by `id`, joining with `women`

This is similar to above but uses a join instead of a match:

```
setkey(data.dt, id)
data.dt[cases][.(women), on = .(name = V1), Age := age][, Age]
```

#### 3. Joining with `women`, then joining with `cases`

This approach selects the rows where `name` matches `women` first (by joining), then it right joins with `cases` so that each case will have its corresponding entry in the result vector:

```
setkey(data.dt, id)
data.dt[.(women), on = .(name = V1), nomatch = 0L][cases, age]
```

#### Discussion

The OP has pointed out that speed is a concern with a production dataset of 500k elements in `cases` and 50M rows in `data.df`. Which of above methods is the fastest for the production dataset may also depend on the number of entries in `women`.

Without proper benchmarking I am reluctant to recommend one of the methods.

Comment: Hi, thank you for a comprehensive answer. I tried the first approach and it works (how fast it is!) but will check with the other two methods and see which one is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you expect `ind` to be either of length 1 or 0 (meaning that the IDs are all different).

Then, you can use {dplyr} to do that very fast:

```
library(dplyr)
results2 <- data.df %>%
  slice(match(cases, id)) %>%
  mutate(res = ifelse(name %in% women, age, NA)) %>%
  pull(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! You are right that it'd be better to leave results as a list. Your solution should work for what I am trying to do, ie. determining the pairs of people who become married in each year but in reality there will be these curious cases with more than 2 people matching the criteria and hence ind greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following code

```
(v<-data.df[cases,])$age[match(v$name,women)>0]
```

or

```
(v<-data.dt[cases,])$age[match(v$name,women)>0]
```